# How to configure environment variable for particular cucumber feature file in eclipse?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am using Cucumber in Java with JUnit and building the project with Maven. I want to use environment variable in the project that should access my entire project. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem title says for a particular cucumber feature file and description of your question says in your whole projects the environment variable should be accessible.
Can you confirm what you want for a particular feature file or for whole project?

In case if you want your environment variables to be accessed in whole project with static value than you can do following things:
Create Single ton class and getter and setter methods to access those environment variables as below

```
public class GlobalClass {

    private static GlobalClass ourInstance;
    private HashMap<String, Object> sessionState = new HashMap<>();

    public static GlobalClass getInstance() {

        if (ourInstance == null) {
            return ourInstance = new ThisRun();
        }
        return ourInstance;
    }
 public void add(String key, Object value) {
        sessionState.put(key, value);
    }
public String getAsString(String key) {
        return sessionState.get(key).toString();
    }
}
```

so you can add the key and values in this single ton class and can access anywhere in the project